# How can I access imageView with tag inside a scrollView?

Tags: ios, imageview, scrollview

```
-(void) addImageviewsToscrollview {
    int cx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = 100;
        rect.size.width = 100;
        rect.origin.x = cx;
        rect.origin.y = 0;

        imageView.tag = i;
        imageView.frame = rect;

        [self.imageScrollview addSubview:imageView];

        cx += imageView.frame.size.width+25;


    }
    [self.imageScrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [self.imageScrollview bounds].size.height)];
}
```

Adding ImageView to the ScrollView. Application is used only for iPad and I'm using storyboard. Should I create a new class and a new UIViewController?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do with those images? Is it slider of images and after clicking this image you want to see images for the full screen with slide show?

Comment: Never use `0` for a tag since that is the default tag for all views.

Answer (score 2):

If you want access any `UIImageView` with any tag, use [`viewWithTag:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag%3a)

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.imageScrollview viewWithTag:1];
```

Just change number 1 with your tag.

Comment: I implemented this line but it's not allowing me to view the picture in fullscreen

Comment: What you are doing after call your `addImageviewsToscrollview` method? Can you updater your question? I need understand what you need after add imagens to your `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding tag by starting 1
imageView.tag = i+1;